# Best ways of handling http verbs in a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, django

I'm following along a Pluralsight course in Django and Angular development. I'm **extremely** new to both framework but have experience with other languages and frameworks.

In the course we are shown how to use `debounce` as an option with a function that is called during `ng-change`. This function `update` uses `http.put` to send a put-request to a local REST API.

However having worked with previous languages the idea of using a `ng-change` to send requests to a web service (even with `debounce` set to 500) seems to be a very silly idea since there will be a lot of unnecessary traffic being sent to the service.

How could one do it better? I was trying to set the `ng-click` on the button to fire off the `update`, but it didn't seem to fire off the event for some reason...

The debounce is missing from the code as I'm simply not sure if I should be using this approach..

**EDIT:**

As has been mentioned in one of the answers it could be a good idea to use `ng-keyup` if I was doing some sort of in-control search with auto-correct/fill, but in this case I'm worried that submitting (updating) data in a database with a `put` request using `ng-keyup` or `ng-change` will create too much overhead traffic.

---

**card.html**

```
<div class="card" ng-hide="edit" ng-click="edit=true">
    <h4> {{ card.title }} </h4>
    <span class="description"> {{ card.description }} </span>
</div>

<div class="card" ng-show="edit">
    <div class="flex">
        <label><strong>Title: &nbsp;</strong></label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="card.title"
                           ng-change="update()" />
    </div>
    <textarea ng-model="card.description"
              ng-change="update()"
              placeholder="Enter description here..."></textarea>
    <button ng-click="edit=false">Close</button>
</div>
```

**card.directive.js**:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('scrumboard.demo')
        .directive('scrumboardCard', CardDirective);

    function CardDirective() {
        return {
            templateUrl: "/static/scrumboard/card.html",
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                let url = '/scrumboard/cards/' + $scope.card.id + '/';
                console.log("Inside");
                $scope.update = function() {
                    console.log("I'm inside");
                    $http.put(url, $scope.card)
                        .finally(function() {
                           edit = false;
                    });
                };
            }]

        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: Why you do not put a search icon and using `ng-click` to hit a call.

Comment: @Ved 
Yeah, that was my thought too, but when I add `ng-click="update()"` to the button it doesn't fire off update. I tried adding `console.log` in a few places, but for some reason it seems as if the event simply not being fired.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with same issue?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to setup a fiddle with Angular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with the text search it is advised to use **`ngKeyup`** instead of ng-change,

```
<textarea ng-model="card.description"
               ng-keyup="update()"
              placeholder="Enter description here..."></textarea>
```

Comment: Isn't the end result the same? Meaning that whenever a key has been pressed (`keyup`) it fires off the event? So you will still be potentially be looking it x put-requests to the server instead of a single in the case of a `ng-click` or similar?

Comment: @geostocker it depends on your requirement, usually if you are doing some free text search, you should be using keyup .

Comment: that seems about right. In case you want in-text autocorrect or such? But if you are submitting data to a server would you really want to use a `ng-keyup`?

Comment: @geostocker then it is always better to use ng-click

Comment: as mentioned in my question the `ng-click` doesn't seem to fire. I added it to my button `ng-click="update()"` and it didn't even seem to enter the function, which leads me to believe something else is wrong with the code. Can you see something?

Comment: It's not in there anymore. I could edit it with a change, but the change was as simple as `ng-click="update()"` in the button. Nothing else. 

Since the question was about using `ng-change` and its potential pitfalls I used that code. I thought having an update on the button's `ng-click` might have made it a bit confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144167/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-geostocker).